# Cannot upload to Robotdyn Mega 2560 PRO MINI?

Tags: uploading, avrdude, error

I get this error trying to upload `avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout`

It is Robotdyn Mega 2560 PRO MINI and a Robotdyn CH340 which I have connected like this: [image]

I installed the CH340 drivers from here https://sparks.gogo.co.nz/ch340.html and I can see it in the device manager.
Connecting the Mega 2560 Pro Mini lights up the `L` and `On` LED but when pressing upload (testing with simple examples as Blink) I get the error and neither RX or TX lights up.

I have tried everything I can think of. What am I doing wrong?

I have confirmed that it is connected to the correct COM-port and I use these settings:

```
Board: Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560
Processor: ATMega2560 (Mega 2560)
```

I have also tried many different USB-cables, short and long, and USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 ports. I use Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: why is the pin header not soldered to board?

Comment: It is now, took the picture before

Comment: @Juraj this is not the same error message?

Comment: but the same troubleshooting

Comment: I now have the adapter and it has swapped RX TX labels, so must be wired RX to RX, TX to TX

Answer (score 1):

Try placing a 100nf capacitor on RST. That is usually required on an FTDI programmer.

See Edgar's post - https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/47431/edgar